# Angular Delete request gets a 404 response - routing problem

Tags: mysql, angular, httprequest

I'm doing an assignment in Angular, and I'm implementing the CRUD operations. Create works, but when it comes to deletion, I'm getting a 404 error while trying to pass the ID of the record.

bankclient-list.html :

```
 <td><button class="btn btn-danger"
             (click)="deleteBankclient(bankclient.id)">Delete</button></td>
```

bankclient-controller.ts :

```
 delete = async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const id = req.params.id;
            const entity = await this.repository.findOne(id);

            if (!entity) {
                return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Not existing entity.' });
            }

            await this.repository.delete(entity);
            res.status(200).send();
        } catch (err) {
            res.status(500).json({ message: 'DELETE HIBA!!' });
        }
    }
```

bankclient-service.ts :

```
async  deleteBankclient(id : number) {
        return await lastValueFrom(this.http.delete<Bankclient>('/api/bankclient?id=' +id))
    }
```

routes.ts in the backend dir :

```
 router.get('/bankclient-list', bankclientController.getAll);
    router.get('/bankclient/:id', bankclientController.getById);
    router.put('/bankclient/:id', bankaccountController.update);
    router.post('/bankclient', bankclientController.create)
    router.delete('/bankclient/:id', bankclientController.delete);
```

So when i click the delete button on the page i get a 404 error
"zone.js:2680
DELETE http://localhost:4200/api/bankclient?id=2 404 (Not Found)
"

Could anyone please help me understand where did i make a mistake in the routing, and how could i actually pass the id parameter to the delete functions?

Comment: What happens when you do the delete from POSTMAN? Do you get the same error? Then you have an issue in your backend services.

Comment: Turns out the mistake was  in bankclient-controller.ts, it should've been  
            const id = parseInt(req.params.id);
            const entity = await this.repository.findOne(({ id: id }));